# Python - importing lots of packages that may not exist with IDE linking

Tags: python

Imagine I have >20 libraries I want to import called a, b, c, d etc.

These libraries may or may not exist, but I want the script to run anyway - think of them as plugins the script runner may have installed.

Obviously, I'll need to catch the ImportErrors then. But if I do it this way:

```py
try:
    import a
    import b
    import c
    import d
except ImportError:
    pass
```

it won't work because the first package that doesn't exist will trip the `except` and the rest of the packages (that could be available) won't be imported.

One solution is to use exec, like so:

```py
imports = ['import a', 'import b', 'import c', 'import d']
for import_cmd in imports:
    try:
        exec(import_cmd)
    except ImportError:
        pass
```

Ignoring that we're using exec() which is generally frowned upon, this accomplishes the correct behaviour. The problem with this method is that since the import statements are strings, IDEs can't link the libraries properly. For example, if this current file was called myfile.py and I went to a different file and tried to import `from myfile import a`, it wouldn't autocomplete and would probably give a linting error, even though at runtime, it would work fine. This would also disable the ability to ctrl + click `a` in the second file to navigate to a, which is annoying.

The solution that accomplishes everything is to try: except: every import, but this is very ugly, repetitive, and it feels like there should be a more scalable solution:

```py
try:
    import a
except ImportError:
    pass
try:
    import b
except ImportError:
    pass
# etc.
```

I've also considered [cog](https://cog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but in my opinion it makes the code harder to understand and maintain (needing to make a file that tells cog all the files to modify, running cog at library install time etc.)

So, are there any solutions to this?

Comment: Well, at the very least, you should use `importlib.import_module("whatever")` instead of `exec("import whatever")`

Comment: Fundamentally, you are running into the problem of static analysis tools not being able to work with dynamically generated outputs. If you *really* value the IDE hinting, then I would just bite the bullet and just use the try: except: every import.

Comment: Found a slightly better solution, using contextlib's suppress() function. Fewer lines of code, but still need to call it on every import because the suppress() context manager exits after the first exception is called.